# fs2 Stream from queue doesn't consume elements

Tags: scala, cats-effect, fs2

I want to create the stream from the queue that will print all the elements into the console.
The current one snippet doesn't print anything:

```
object TestApp extends App {

  implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

  private val value: IO[(fs2.Stream[IO, Unit], String => IO[Unit], () => IO[Unit])] = for {
    queue <- Queue.noneTerminated[IO, String]
  } yield {
    val stream: fs2.Stream[IO, Unit] = queue.dequeue.map(println)

    def send(msg: String): IO[Unit] = queue.enqueue1(Some(msg))

    def close(): IO[Unit] = queue.enqueue1(None)

    (stream, send _, close _)
  }

  val (stream, send, close) = value.unsafeRunSync()

  send("msg1").unsafeRunSync()
  send("msg2").unsafeRunSync()

}
```

what is wrong with stream creation?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're merely creating a queue and creating a description of the stream. In order to run the stream, you need to call `compile` which will expose several methods, that would allow running and consuming values of the steam, like `toList`, `fold` or `drain`

In your case you're not really interested in values, since you only want to print them, so you should use `drain`:

```
implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)
implicit val timer: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)

private val value: IO[(fs2.Stream[IO, Unit], String => IO[Unit], () => IO[Unit])] = for {
  queue <- Queue.noneTerminated[IO, String]
} yield {
  //I changed map to evalMap, since printing is effect and should be wrapped in IO
  val stream: fs2.Stream[IO, Unit] = queue.dequeue.evalMap(v => IO(println(v)))

  def send(msg: String): IO[Unit] = queue.enqueue1(Some(msg))

  def close(): IO[Unit] = queue.enqueue1(None)

  (stream, send _, close _)
}

val (stream, send, close) = value.unsafeRunSync()

send("msg1").unsafeRunSync()
send("msg2").unsafeRunSync()
//Closing of stream will be delayed by 5s and run in separate fiber
close().delayBy(5.seconds).start.unsafeRunSync()

//steam would block here until it's closed
stream.compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()
```